# How to pass Shift + F10 for installing Windows 11 instead of opening up Microsoft Teams

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-11, vmware-workstation, microsoft-teams

I'm installing `Windows 11` on `VMware Workstation`.

The following link says:

> In Command Prompt, type the OOBE\BYPASSNRO command to bypass network
> requirements on Windows 11 and press Enter.

https://pureinfotech.com/bypass-internet-connection-install-windows-11/

I have tried to press `Shift + F10` by following the guide, but every time the "`Microsoft Teams`" application will be started instead.

It seems the `Shift + F10` is already used by `Microsoft Teams,` the following link says:

> Open the context menu. Shift+F10

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-teams-for-personal-and-small-business-use-cd03efd1-e38c-4009-b64b-60dcff43c794

How to pass `Shift + F10` into `VMware workstation` for installing `Windows 11` offline?

Comment: @spikey_richie, Thank you so much. I tried the Shift + Fn + F10, it works now. Please add your comment as answer then I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overcome this limitation by also passing in <kbd>Fn</kbd>, so in your case you'd press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all possible all possible combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, but nothing worked.

Then i clicked on that `Accessibility` icon and enabled on-screen keyboard and then selected <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> again and it opened the cmd prompt this time, but it does not come into focus, to do that you can then use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> on your physical keyboard.